# Issues with Ubuntu Linux installation on a Windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I’m trying to install Ubuntu Linux on my Windows 8.1 laptop. I’m being told I need to “Disable Secure Boot” within my UEFI firmware settings. But the only way my laptop will allow me to do so is to switch over to BIOS Legacy Mode, which I was told would not help. Is there another way to do this? Or does anyone know how to create and mount the ISO on a new partition within the Windows side?

Device
    Acer Aspire - Intel Based -
    Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering in the UEFI Firmware Settings for an hour I was able to come up with this. In order (for me) to keep the UEFI boot mode WITH disabled Secure Boot, I had to set the 'supervisor password' and after doing so I was able to navigate to my 'Boot' tab and then I was able to disable Secure Boot.